# Speech recognition in C#

Tags: c#, speech-to-text

I'm doing a project that involves speech recognition. But here i don't just need to recognize simple commands, I need my application to identify a  lengthy sentence. Such as "My name is jack, I live in UK". 
I'm currently using Microsoft SAPI5.1. But when i execute my application it doesn't take what I'm saying accurately.

Can any one give me a better option of getting this done. I need to capture what I'm saying and convert it to a Text.
Please help

Comment: have you trained Windows from the control panel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option for speech recognition would have to be [Nuance's Dragon Naturally Speaking](http://www.nuance.com/dragon/index.htm). Note that it is a commercial solution though.

Comment: Is this a library or an application?